# Crear una imagen a partir de un hash. [Node/JS]

Tags: javascript, nodejs, imagen

necesito crear imagenes a partir de hashes de archivos.

Tengo los hashes de los archivos y puedo generar arrayBuffer/Blob/loquesea con valores de 0 a 255 que tambien puedo agrupar de 3 en 3 y generar valores RGB pero no encuentro la manera de codificarlo como PNG/JPG.

Debe ser facil pero no lo consigo de ninguna manera.
Este ha sido el vago intento que he hecho porque no se me ocurre nada.

```javascript
var hash = "b3bdce59b7dda5eb91340cf53ab3926744262ef0025d4b15f0e2e76745fbe239"
var b64 = btoa(hash)
var blob = new Blob([ b64 ], { type: 'image/png' })
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

Y después he creado manualmente una etiqueta de imagen y como src le he puesto la url pero obviamente no ha funcionado.

Comment: _"Debe ser fácil"..._ La verdad es que NO, porque no basta con colocar códigos en un archivo jpg/gif/png, estos deben tener sentido para mostrarse como imagen. Tal vez podrías crear una imagen con [código QR](http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/), pero no basta el _hash_, debes asignar algunas propiedades.

Comment: @Triby con facil me refería a que suponía que ya habría alguna base hecha como para ir haciendo yo algo del tipo (new Png()).addPixel. Pero eso, buscaba algo como justo que me has pasado, porque un qr me vale, lo que pasa que no he visto librerías que no me obliguen a pintarlo en un canvas. Voy a investigar esa que me pasas a ver que creo que no la he visto antes.